# Oracle SQL: How to obtain values that can't get converted with to_number?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I trying to obtain from my table all the rows that cant be converted with the function `TO_NUMBER` or values in which the function would fail, for instance if I have the following input:

```
SAMPLE_COL
'1.1'
'333'
'3A'
'5%'
```

It should retrieve:

```
SAMPLE_COL
'3A'
'5%'
```

Comment: this sounds like a REGEX issue.  have you considered that?

Comment: And also this points out bad data type use, but probably you can't change the column type at this point

Comment: @OldProgrammer - closing the thread as a duplicate was premature. You linked to a thread from 2011. The best solution today (using the "default on error" extension to `to_number`) didn't exist in 2011, so it seems pretty moronic to add an answer along those lines to THAT thread.

Comment: @mathguy - but this question is tagged for 11g, so that wouldn't be an appropriate answer here either? There's probably another more generic question that includes old and new solutions, so if you can find one that can be added as an additional dupe target.

Comment: @AlexPoole - Now (in 2022) it makes sense to post a solution using features from 2015, even if the question is tagged 11g; at least this gives a reason (to the OP or to others in his position) to consider upgrading their db version. It would also help others who have the same question now, but without the "old version" limitation. It would make no sense to offer such a solution to a thread from 2011.